# How can I get an HLS stream current time with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm trying to get the position of an HLS stream that `AVPlayer` is reproducing, relative to the beginning of the stream.

All I have been able to get is the time from the beginning of the playback (with `AVPlayer.currentTime()`) and the date when the stream started (with `AVPlayerItem.currentDate()`).

I am 100% sure that the offset in seconds is embedded in every MPEG TS file, I just can't find a way to access that value from AVPlayer or AVPlayerItem.

FFProbe's output for a test TS chunk:

```
ffprobe version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'toCharlie.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:08.40, start: 16117.400000, bitrate: 1808 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:1[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 720x1280, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s
```

The offset in seconds is there (`start: 16117.400000`).

Is it even possible to get the actual current time from the start of the stream?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: for clarity, the HLS stream is a live stream, not a VOD stream.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @Tometoyou It's been a long time, but if I'm not mistaken, we fixed it from the source, we changed how the HLS was encoded, but I really don't remember what the problem was. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try some `addObserver` for `AVPlayer` like this:

```
player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
```

and using function:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {.....
```

to track the status reponse in that via KVO concept from iOS

Comment: Yes, and it can't work. AVPlayer cannot load from the beginning of the stream, because it's a live stream and it's not seekable.